# How can I go only once in a switch case?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

I make a quiz in C# and my questions are randomly asked with a random number. The problem is I just want to go once in each cases. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your answers.

```
Random rdmNb = new Random();
int rdm1 = rdmNb.Next(1, 11);

switch (rdm1)
{
    case 1:           
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ1;
        break;
    case 2:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ2;
        break;
    case 3:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ3;
        break;
    case 4:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ4;
        break;
    case 5:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ5;
        break;
    case 6:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ6;
        break;
    case 7:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ7;
        break;
    case 8:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ8;
        break;
    case 9:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ9;
        break;
    case 10:
        lblQuesttion.Text = strQ10;
        break;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'go once'?

Comment: go one time

bad english sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a list of your questions

```
List<string> questions = new List<string>()
{
   strQ1,strQ2,strQ3,strQ4,strQ5,strQ6,strQ7,strQ8,strQ9,strQ10
};
```

Then change your random generation to find a question from the list

```
Random rdmNb = new Random();
int rdm1 = rdmNb.Next(0, questions.Count);

lblQuesttion.Text = questions[rdm1];
```

and remove the question asked from the list

```
questions.RemoveAt(rdm1);
```

no switch required....

Be sure to declare the Random variable outside the loop that drives your selection of the next question. As in this example

```
// Declare globally the random generator, not inside the question loop
Random rdmNb = new Random();

while (questions.Count > 0)
{
    int rdm1 = rdmNb.Next(0, questions.Count);
    string curQuestion = questions[rdm1];
    questions.RemoveAt(rdm1);

    lblQuestion.Text = curQuestion;

    ... ?code to handle the user input?
}
```

**EDIT**
Declaring and initializing your question list with global scope inside the form.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
     // Declaration at global level
     List<string> questions;

     public MyForm()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         LoadQuestions();
     }

     private void LoadQuestions()
     {
        questions = new List<string>()
        {
            strQ1,strQ2,strQ3,strQ4,strQ5,strQ6,strQ7,strQ8,strQ9,strQ10
        };

        // In future you could change this method to load your questions
        // from a file or a database.....
     }

}
```

Comment: I have a problem with your answer: I call several times in the method in which I ask the question and each time the list is declared thus with the 10 questions, it is thus re-initialized. Do you have another solution? :)

Comment: You need to move the initialization of the list at a global level. Assuming you have a WinForms application then declare the list variable at the global level, then in the  Form_Load event initialize it with the sequence of questions (perhaps in future you want to read them from a file or database). Provide also a method that you can call to reinitialize (readd the questions to) the list

Comment: Have you got an example ? I don't know the syntax to initialize something at a global level.

Comment: Is this a winforms application?

Answer (score 1):

You could always to this:

```
List<string> questions = new List<string>()
{
   strQ1,strQ2,strQ3,strQ4,strQ5,strQ6,strQ7,strQ8,strQ9,strQ10
};

var rnd = new Random();
var questionsStack = new Stack<string>(questions.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()));
```

Now you just `.Pop()` questions from the stack as you need them, like this:

```
if (questionsStack.Count > 0)
{
    lblQuesttion.Text = questionsStack.Pop();
}
```

Comment: An example for me ? :)